# jQuery change image onClick from a link

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery to rotate through images when a link is clicked, then go back to the original image again.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('img', this).attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
      return oldSrc == 'images/1.jpg' ? 'images/2.jpg' : 'images/1.jpg';
  });
  $('#link').toggle(400);
  return false;
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="toggle">button</a>
<img src="images/1.jpg" height="68" width="216" alt="" id="#link" />
```

Not quite sure what wrong here, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong:

`$('img', this)` will select image tags inside the link that was clicked. So, in this case it won't select anything.

`$('#link').toggle(400);` will show and hide the img on alternate clicks.

and finally as previously mentioned, the ID of the image should be `link` rather than `#link`.

To make your code work I would change it to this:

```
$('#toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#link').attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
      return oldSrc == 'images/1.jpg' ? 'images/2.jpg' : 'images/1.jpg';
  });
});
```

And the image tag to this:

```
<img src="images/1.jpg" height="68" width="216" alt="" id="link" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code:

```
$('img', this).attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
    return oldSrc == 'images/1.jpg' ? 'images/2.jpg' : 'images/1.jpg';
});
```

is looking for an image that's a descendent of the `<a>` element, which isn't the case with your given HTML (it's a sibling). It should instead be:

```
$(this).next('img').attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
    return oldSrc == 'images/1.jpg' ? 'images/2.jpg' : 'images/1.jpg';
});
```

And, as Anton has already said, the ID attribute for your image needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="toggle">button</a>
<img src="images/1.jpg" height="68" width="216" alt="" id="link" />
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#toggle').click(function () {
        $('#link').attr('src', function (i, oldSrc) {
            return oldSrc == 'images/1.jpg' ? 'images/2.jpg' : 'images/1.jpg';
        });
       $('#link').toggle(400);
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/SGKpT/)

Comment: Ok thats great thanks, it works however I need to add a few more images to rotate, after: 'images/2.jpg' I tried adding but broke the script? The error I get in Firebug is: SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression

Comment: @user2890068 for this you can create an `array of images` and get the `image` by `next index` from the `current index`.